# I am trying to plot a function and its derivatives with matlab. Getting the error "inner matrix dimensions must agree"

Tags: matlab

I want to plot x(t)=t*exp(-3*t)+0.25*exp(-3*t), and its first and second time derivatives.

I cannot even get the first plot correct. This is what I have done.

```
t = [0:0.01:3];
x = t*exp(-3*t)+0.25*exp(-3*t);
figure
plot(t,x);
```

From what I understand, that is saying that t goes from 0 to 3 in steps of 0.01 and x is the function I defined at that t. MatLab gives me this error

"Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree."

Can someone please let me know what's going on? I'm a matlab noob. I use mathematica quite a bit and I have used octave for making plots of data, but never to plot functions. I always do that stuff with mathematica!

Comment: If you have Mathematica, why not do this there? x[t_] := t Exp[-3 t] + 0.25 Exp[-3 t]. Plot[{x[t], x'[t], x''[t]}, {t, 3, 0.1}]

Comment: Why are you using Matlab at all?  Plotting and taking derivatives of functions is much easier in Mathematica or Maple.

Comment: @Rich Williams : Also, pure Matlab questions with no math content are discouraged here.  StackOverflow might be a better place to post.

Answer (score 6):

you have to have

```
x = t.*exp(-3.*t)+0.25*exp(-3.*t)
```

this will do element by element multiplication

`.*` is the element by element multiplication for a vector, `*` is just multiplication.

Answer (score 3):

Plotting and taking derivatives of functions in Matlab is perfectly easy. First you just need to use the [symbolic math](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/index.html) capabilities:

```
syms t;
x = t*exp(-3*t)+0.25*exp(-3*t);
xdot = diff(x,t,1)
xddot = diff(x,t,2)
```

Then to plot these you have several options. You can substitute in numeric values using [`subs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html), which automatically vectorizes your equations so you don't need to worry about adding `.*`:

```
t_ = 0:0.01:3;
x_ = subs(x,t,t_);
xdot_ = subs(xdot,t,t_);
xddot_ = subs(xddot,t,t_);
plot(t_,x_,'b',t_,xdot_,'g',t_,xddot_,'r')
```

Or you can use the [`ezplot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ezplot.html) function to directly plot the symbolic function over a range:

```
subplot(131);
ezplot(x,[0 3]);
subplot(132);
ezplot(xdot,[0 3]);
subplot(133);
ezplot(xddot,[0 3]);
```

The function [`fplot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fplot.html) is another option if you convert your symbolic equations to numeric functions. This can be done manually or via the [`matlabFunction`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html) function:

```
subplot(131);
fplot(matlabFunction(x),[0 3])
subplot(132);
fplot(matlabFunction(xdot),[0 3])
subplot(133);
fplot(matlabFunction(xddot),[0 3])
```